# Is there a way to send Google Notifications to the Mac OS X Notification Center or to Growl?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, notifications, growl

Is there a way to send Google Chrome Notifications (you know that annoying little bell in the menu bar) to the OS X Notification Center? Instead of receiving notifications in different positions and styles (native OS X Notifications, Growl, Chrome Notifications), I would like to see them in one place - the OS X Notification Center.

Is there an easy way to configure this, or a tool that can help with doing this?

**Update**

I've found [Hiss](http://collect3.com.au/hiss/), which allows to send Growl messages to the OS X Notification Center, which is great, since it minimizes the number of notification styles.

In addition to the question above, is there a way to send Chrome Notifications to Growl? That might allow to use Hiss to finally route them to the OS X Notification Center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Chrome 57 for the Mac, go to `chrome://flags/` and find the **Native Notifications** settings, enable them and restart Chrome.