# Force Chrome to use OS X notifications?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, notifications

I'd like to find a way to use OS X native notifications instead of the Chrome notifications.

I have read something about using a Growl extension and then redirect Growl to OS X Notifications Center using Hiss app, but I never used Growl and for what I've read seems like it was used only on old versions of OS X.

Is there any way?

Comment: sound similar to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/178218/is-there-a-way-to-send-google-notifications-to-the-mac-os-x-notification-center

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can with this experimental feature.
Open `chrome://flags/#enable-native-notifications` to enable the feature, then restart Chrome.

Comment: Yes it wasn't available at the time of this question was posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can now go to chrome://flags and enable "Enable native notifications. Mac", and it works as it should.

Comment: Consider adding some details to this post to make it more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to this is ***No***

In order for Chrome to send an alert to OS X's notification center, an API call must be initiated - from the browser to OS X.  Technically, an add-on could be developed that would address this, however, Google seems to have left open the idea that they would be bring this feature to fruition.

[Chrome's notification center is the latest casualty in the war against browser bloat](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3011393/browsers/chromes-notification-center-is-the-latest-casualty-in-the-war-against-browser-bloat.html)

Unfortunately, this is just something we are going to have to wait for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an answer here because now Chrome on macOS uses by default the native notifications system. You don't have to perform any specific action anymore.